# Textarea overflowing text when typing in repeated characters

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, textarea

I have this weird issue that I can't seem to solve.

I made this comment section where you type into the text area, hit DONE and your comment shows up in the comment section (pretty straight forward).
The issue here though is that if you type a "normal" text into the area it produces it properly with line breaks when the text hits the border of the container, but if you type one character continuously it produces it all in one line ... (see picture below).

Has anyone had this issue before and any ideas on how to fix that, just to prevent idiots from bugging my application.

Thanks in advance, have a lovely week!

[image]

Comment: please provide code next time

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've just figured it out ... in CSS: word-break: break-word 
... that's literally all I had to do. Sorry to bother you and I hope this helps others if anything!

Answer (score 0):

the issue is because there is no whitespace to break the word, as suggested use `word-break: break-all`

you can also style it by using `overflow: hidden`

and also hyphens `hyphens: auto;`

> https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this is what you looking for,**

```
div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```